# Display large text from database on asp.net page with proper spacing and indent?

Tags: asp.net, html

I was just wondering out of curiosity if it was possible to display large text from a database in a HTML or asp.net page with proper indenting and spacing?

As of right now, I have it displayed in a textbox and I'm using a highlight specific text feature incorporated in my site that doesn't function ONLY when the length of the text is greater then actual textbox. So I was thinking of displaying the data on a page and considering using Response.Write but the displayed text is all bunched together without proper indenting or spacing.

Ex.) instead of..."Hey Everyone   how is everyone doing today? I am sample text"...is possible to display it as...

"Hey Everyone

How is everyone today? I am sample text"

Would anyone guide to any proper method that I could use or know of any info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> New Line will be like \r\n in code behind text

Now, you can use Span or Literal control like below in HTML

### HTML Side

```
<span id="span" runat="server"></span>

<asp:Literal id="literal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

### Code Behind side

```
span.InnerHtml = yourtext.Replace("\r\n","<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about what format the text is stored in the DB (I'm assuming it's just regular spacing & carriage returns.

You could put it between `<pre>` tags. e.g.

**ASPX**

```
<pre>
   <asp:Label ID="myTextArea" runat="server" />
</pre>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
myTextArea.Text = //Code to get text string from DB
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are carraige returns already embedded in the text, you could do replace them with `<p>` tags, like:

```
string value = // get value from database ;
string formattedValue = string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", value.Replace("\r", "</p><p>"));
```